# How can I migrate a Windows 11 from MBR boot to GPT without reinstalling?

Tags: partitioning, uefi, mbr, gpt

At start, i wanted to do it by myself, but any guide that i found just doesnt work.it turned out to be a small problem at first, all I had to do was create an efi partition on my system disk, but in the process, I realized that I couldn't do it on an mbr disk. So, than i realized that I need to change mbr to gpt on disk, where windows at, but mbr2gpt says that disk layput validation is failed(so i dont know how convert will go(maybe it wont)). i have drive, that signed as system one, but it is my oldest hdd(i think that because of it i am here(i should disconnect it when i was installing OS)). So can i convert all my drives to gpt(including OS one) (disk 0 - is hdd where system partition is(i guess) disk 3 is m2, where OS is located) maybe i could somehow move system partition to disk3, but i am not sure will it make some difference.

Edit: setuperr log error from mbr2gpt.exe
"ValidateLayout: Wrong boot partition count, expected 1 but found 0.
Disk layout validation failed for disk 3"

Screenshot of Disk Management:

[image: Disk Management]

Comment: Can you show the current partition list (e.g. as a screenshot of `diskmgmt.msc`)?

Comment: Your computer must be UEFI - BIOS shouldn't be used for Windows 11. You only need to convert the system disk to GPT - Windows 11 can use non-boot MBR disks. Question: How did you manage to install Windows 11 on MBR? I think that the best solution is to reinstall Windows 11 from scratch while formatting the system disk as GPT (and losing all data). Note that in the UEFI you need to enable Secure boot and disable Legacy Boot.

Comment: @u1686_grawity i added diskpart (or you want to see something else?)

Comment: @mind.LESS: Yeah, that only shows whole disks – I'd like to see how all of the partitions are arranged.

Comment: The short answer is `mbr2gpt`. The long answer will have to wait—unless someone else writes it. // Please provide a screenshot of Disk Management instead, it'll have all drives.

Comment: @u1686_grawity i edited picture to diskmgmt.msc

Comment: @DanielB i added screenshot of Disk Management instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>It seems that you have an old-style installation (i.e. what Windows XP and earlier would've used), where a single partition contains both the bootloader and the OS. This won't work at all with mbr2gpt as it expects to already have the "Microsoft Reserved Partition" with Bootmgr in it that it could transform into an EFI System Partition.</del>

The approach I would use if I had a lot of time would be to use Diskpart/Diskmgmt to shrink the C: volume by ~500 MB, then use Linux GParted to move it to the right (creating a gap at the beginning) – moving 1 TB is the slow part – then create a new "Microsoft Reserved Partition" there (can be done with Diskpart, official Microsoft instructions exist) and use 'bcdboot' to populate it. This would leave you with a standard-looking partition setup that mbr2gpt might accept.

Moving 1 TB on an HDD is both slow and risky, however, so instead you could just create the Microsoft Reserved Partition *at the end* of the disk. EFI won't mind that (and since it's well within the 2TB limit, BIOS won't mind either). I'm not sure if mbr2gpt will be fine with that, though, but it's worth a try – and can be done all within Windows:

0. Just in case, create a Windows install USB stick, and maybe also a Linux live USB stick.
1. Shrink C: by 500 MB or so.
2. Create a new 'primary' partition. Format as NTFS.
3. Run `bcdboot c:\windows /s X:` where X is the new drive letter of that partition. This will install Bootmgr there.
4. If bcdboot succeeds, set the new partition as 'Active' (right-click). This tells the MBR to actually look for Bootmgr there.
5. <del>Reboot to see if it worked. If it boots, mbr2gpt it. If it didn't boot, setting the original C: as 'Active' (e.g. from a live USB) will return to the original state.</del> Actually, just mbr2gpt it without a reboot.

(Side note: "Microsoft Reserved Partition" means different things in MBR and GPT. In the former, it's the rough equivalent of an EFI System Partition; in the latter it's a ~16MB space-filler partition that does nothing at all.)

If mbr2gpt still refuses, one alternative would be to use the 'gdisk' tool to do the conversion of just the partition table (it's mainly a Linux tool but I believe it also has a Windows version), then use Windows' bcdboot.exe to build a fresh EFI System Partition.

This will require you to have a Windows installation USB stick handy.

1. Run `gdisk` on the physical disk device. It'll do the conversion automatically; just use `w` to save and quit.
2. After that, the disk is GPT but still has a BIOS-style Bootmgr, so it's no longer bootable in either BIOS or EFI. Instead, boot your Windows USB stick and press Shift-F10 to open the console.
3. Use Diskpart to find the drive letters of the OS partition and of the newly created partition. (The C: partition might not necessarily be C: when booted from USB.)
4. Use bcdboot as described above, but with the `/f UEFI` option.

Comment: So this is changing my perspective then. Before that i thought that my boot partition is on old hdd(0), but now i understand what you mean. And after all this researching i just dont understand why win11 installed like that. Why did it install like that and forced me to study and watch all this, did they already tell me all this during installation, but I just unknowingly changed the installation to the old one? after all, I installed the OS on a new clean SSD. maybe there is some other version of why everything is so wrong with partitions?

Comment: Well, no, I think I've actually misinterpreted your screenshot a bit – I missed the 'System' label on the partition that's on disk 0. I'll edit the post later.

Comment: il be waiting. Anyway  Thanks a lot, such an answer required a lot of knowledge and a lot of effort to turn all this into an algorithm. i think that i somehow need to delete boot partition from old drive, create new one on nwme, and than mbr2gpt should work(knowing how it all happens, I think something will go wrong again)

Comment: hello again, what do you think I need to do, try moving boot partition using bsd or you definitely need to map the disk. If I pull out the windows folder and other folders (users, program files), outside the system I will turn boot to the beginning of the disk, and then copy these folders to disk again. Will windows notice this?

Comment: It probably will notice that, unless you use tools that take care to preserve the various metadata (e.g. file security/owner information) and special file types (the several different kinds of reparse points). `dism /capture-image` into a .wim file is a good option, although it still captures not quite 100% of all metadata (and does not scale well to large amounts of data; archiving a terabyte HDD through dism will take really long). Just place the system partition at the end instead.

Comment: does it have any consequences? (system at the end?)

Comment: Windows _shouldn't_ care (though I'm not sure how it will handle the recovery partition but I think that should be fine). EFI firmware really won't care. (Even BIOS also wouldn't care as long as it fit within the 2TiB boundary.)

Comment: thanks alot again. I will try bcdboot then.